# Full height cover background with sticky navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, sticky

I have a sticky navbar and want to add a full-page cover.

I can use this for the cover: `<body style="background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1660665416754-e0c780103b3c) no-repeat center center; background-size: cover; height: 100vh;">`

The problem is the sticky navbar disappears as soon I scroll past the full height. Screencast (the dark image is the full-page cover):

[image: Sticky header disappears]

How do I fix this?

> To try it yourself, please open https://demo.gethugothemes.com/hargo/site/index.html and, using Chrome Inspector, change the `<body>` to the one I mentioned above.

Comment: Can you post more of your HTML? This looks like an issue with your sticky header and not the background

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing the sticky nav from `position: sticky` to `position: fixed`.

The semantics are different, but it works for me.